# How do I to resolved syntax issue with use of SupportSQLiteOpenHelpe when implementing SQLCipherr

Tags: java, android, android-room, sqlcipher

I am attempting to implement encryption of an Android Room Database using SupportHelper and SupportFactory classes I obtained from Github in conjunction with importing androidx.db.SupportSQLOpenHelper and androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase;

The current issue I am getting is a statement as follows:

```
standardHelper =

new SupportSQLiteOpenHelper(configuration.context, configuration.name,
null, configuration.callback.version, hook) { }
```

it generates the following error/warning

Class ‘Anynymous class derived from SupportSQLIteOpenHelper’ must either be declared abstract or implement method ‘getDatabaseName() in SupportSQLiteOpenHelper’ (note, it also looks for 3 other methods … close(), getWritableDatabase, getReadableDatabase).
How do I resolve this? Thanks in advance for your assistance**

My full SupportHelper class is

```
import static androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Constraints.TAG;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase;
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteOpenHelper;

public class SupportHelper implements SupportSQLiteOpenHelper
      {
    private SupportSQLiteOpenHelper standardHelper;
    private byte[] passphrase;
    private final boolean clearPassphrase;
    private Context context;
    private Context appContext;
    private SupportSQLiteDatabase db;
    private SupportSQLiteDatabase resultBack;
    private SQLiteDatabaseHook hook;
    SupportHelper(final SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Configuration configuration,
                  byte[] passphrase, final SQLiteDatabaseHook hook,
                  boolean clearPassphrase) {
        context = configuration.context;
        this.passphrase = passphrase;
        appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(appContext);
        this.clearPassphrase = clearPassphrase;
        this.hook = hook;

        standardHelper =
                new SupportSQLiteOpenHelper(configuration.context, configuration.name,
                        null, configuration.callback.version, hook) {

                    public void onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "CheckingInRoomDatabase SupportHelper onCreate: ");
                        configuration.callback.onCreate(db);
                        Log.i(TAG, "CheckingInRoomDatabase SupportHelper onCreate Callback: ");
                    }

                    public void onUpgrade(SupportSQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                                          int newVersion) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "CheckingInRoomDatabase SupportHelper onUpgrade: ");
                        configuration.callback.onUpgrade(db, oldVersion,
                                newVersion);
                    }

                    public void onDowngrade(SupportSQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                                            int newVersion) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "CheckingInRoomDatabase SupportHelper onDowngrade: ");
                        configuration.callback.onDowngrade(db, oldVersion,
                                newVersion);
                    }

                    public void onOpen(SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "CheckingInRoomDatabase SupportHelper onOpen: ");
                        configuration.callback.onOpen(db);
                    }

                    public void onConfigure(SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "CheckingInRoomDatabase SupportHelper onConfigure: ");
                        configuration.callback.onConfigure(db);
                    }
                };
    }

    @Override
    public String getDatabaseName() {

        return standardHelper.getDatabaseName();
    }

    @Override
    public void setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        Log.i(TAG, "CheckingInRoomDatabase SupportHelper setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled: ");
        //standardHelper.setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(enabled);
        Log.i(TAG, "setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled: ");
    }

    @Override
    public SupportSQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
        SupportSQLiteDatabase result;
        Log.i(TAG, "CheckingInRoomDatabase SupportHelper getWritableDatabase2: ");
        try {
            result = standardHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLiteException ex){
            if(passphrase != null){
                boolean isCleared = true;
                for(byte b : passphrase){
                    isCleared = isCleared && (b == (byte)0);
                }
                if (isCleared) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("The passphrase appears to be cleared. This happens by " +
                            "default the first time you use the factory to open a database, so we can remove the " +
                            "cleartext passphrase from memory. If you close the database yourself, please use a " +
                            "fresh SupportFactory to reopen it. If something else (e.g., Room) closed the " +
                            "database, and you cannot control that, use SupportFactory boolean constructor option " +
                            "to opt out of the automatic password clearing step. See the project README for more information.", ex);
                }
            }
            throw ex;
        }
        if (clearPassphrase && passphrase != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < passphrase.length; i++) {
                passphrase[i] = (byte)0;
            }
        }
        resultBack = result;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public SupportSQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
        Log.i(TAG, "CheckingInRoomDatabase SupportHelper getReadableDatabase: ");
        return getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        Log.i(TAG, "CheckingInRoomDatabase SupportHelper close: ");
        standardHelper.close();
    }
```

My full SupportFactory class is as follows:

```
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteOpenHelper;

public class SupportFactory implements SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Factory {
    private final byte[] passphrase;
    private final SQLiteDatabaseHook hook;
    private final boolean clearPassphrase;

    public SupportFactory(byte[] passphrase) {
        this(passphrase, (SQLiteDatabaseHook)null);
    }

    public SupportFactory(byte[] passphrase, SQLiteDatabaseHook hook) {
        this(passphrase, hook, true);
    }

    public SupportFactory(byte[] passphrase, SQLiteDatabaseHook hook,
                          boolean clearPassphrase) {
        this.passphrase = passphrase;
        this.hook = hook;
        this.clearPassphrase = clearPassphrase;
    }

    @Override
    public SupportSQLiteOpenHelper create(SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Configuration configuration) {
        return new SupportHelper(configuration, passphrase, hook, clearPassphrase);
    }
}
~~
```